# Get htaccess to add value as GET variable when redirecting

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Simply put, what I want to achieve is this,

www.example.com/show-products/food should be redirected to 
www.example.com/show_products.php?cat_id=1

or www.example.com/show-products/clothes should be redirected to 
www.example.com/show_products.php?cat_id=8

But, I want htaccess to send the GET variables from the URL to the script as well.
So www.example.com/show-products/food?sort=price&sort_order=asc should be redirected to
www.example.com/show_products.php?cat_id=1?sort=price&sort_order=asc&cat_id=1

I know the way I formulated the question is not the best but hopefully you can make sense of it.

Thanks.

---

I found the answer, it's easier than I expected, the condition is:

```
RewriteRule ^food(/)?$ show_products.php?cat_id=1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Comment: How do you know what `cat_id` corresponds to each named category?

Comment: Tim, there are few categories, I was thinking of doing an entrance for each one in the .htaccess file.

Comment: Ah, alright. Also, if you find the answer to your own question, it's totally fine to (and recommended that you) post an answer yourself and accept that answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way that you've done it is fine, but keep in mind that you can also use the [`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) flag. This automatically appends the existing query string to the query string which you generate with your rewrite, handling the concatenation for you automatically.

This would look like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^food(/)?$ show_products.php?cat_id=1 [QSA]
```